# Using variables as they are made in a loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, variables

```
i = 0
loc_file = []
open_file=open('test.txt','r')
file_lines=open_file.readlines()
file = file_lines[0].strip()  # First Line
for _ in (file_lines[1]):
  exec(f'c{i} = _')
  loc_file.append()
  i = i + 1
print(loc_file)
```

I am trying to use variables as they are assigned in as little code as possible, but nothing I have tried to put for

```
loc_file.append()
```

has seemed to work.

Comment: Instead of a list of variables named `c0`, `c1`, `c2` ... just use one list called `c` and access like `c[0]`, `c[1]`, `c[2]`...

Comment: What is `loc_file` and what do you want to append to it? Also see answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)